# Thread safe ReferenceEquals

Tags: c#, excel

I try to create an VSTO Addin. Within this I store Worksheet objects in a list. For my Addin it is important to use a delayed function call to execute it in a own Thread. So when I call `TestClass.run()` I go 2 times through my list of worksheets, first before calling the delayed function and second within the delayed function. The second call cannot match the worksheet instance. How can I achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Timers;

namespace Ventron.VRange
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private static List<OuterWorksheet> sheetList = new List<OuterWorksheet>();

        public static void run(Range range)
        {
            TestClass.sheetList.Add(new OuterWorksheet(range.Worksheet));
            TestClass.getWorkSheet(range.Worksheet);

            ElapsedEventHandler delayedFn = delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Timers.Timer theTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
                if (theTimer.Enabled)
                {
                    theTimer.Stop();
                    theTimer.Enabled = false;
                    theTimer.Dispose();
                    theTimer = null;
                    TestClass.getWorkSheet(range.Worksheet);
                }
            };

            System.Timers.Timer timerInstance = new System.Timers.Timer(1);
            timerInstance.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(delayedFn);
            timerInstance.Interval = 1;
            timerInstance.Enabled = true;
        }

        internal static OuterWorksheet getWorkSheet(Worksheet worksheet)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("*****************************\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(worksheet.CodeName + "\n");

            foreach (OuterWorksheet outerWS in TestClass.sheetList)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(outerWS.worksheet.CodeName + "\n");
                if (outerWS.worksheet.Equals(worksheet))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Worksheets are equal\n");
                    return outerWS;
                } else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Worksheets are not equal\n");
            }
            return null;
        }

        internal class OuterWorksheet
        {
            public Worksheet worksheet { get; private set; }
            public OuterWorksheet(Worksheet worksheet)
            {
                this.worksheet = worksheet;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
*****************************
Sheet5
Sheet5
Worksheets are equal

*****************************
Sheet5
Sheet5
Worksheets are not equal
```

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you are getting a worksheet, it is generating a new wrapper instance around the COM object that is exposed by excel, so they are never equal by reference.  Excel requires unique sheet names, so just compare the names when you are checking for equality.

Comment: But the names are not unique are they? - EDIT: Cool looks like they are. This was my workaround idea but I thought they can be changed by the user. Thx..

Comment: In any Excel workbook, the sheet names are unique. I just went to Excel to double check

Comment: Sheet names are unique within a workbook, but can be changed by the user. Sheet Code Names are also unique within a workbook but cannot be changed by the user.